Missing ARIA Labels After Upgrading to Flutter Web 3.22.2
Since upgrading to Flutter web 3.22.2, I've noticed that my ARIA labels have disappeared when running flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html and flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit. How can I restore my ARIA labels?
I tried:
flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html 

and
flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit.


Please file issues for this type of thing! https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new/choose
